# Top alignment of three minipages while inserting TikZ images

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, minipage

I want to have top alignment of three minipages. I tried the following code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\begin{minipage}[t][][s]{.45\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  pool/.style={
    circle, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, thick,
    inner sep=0pt, minimum size=10mm
  }
]
  \node[pool] (A)              {A};
  \node[pool] (B) [right=of A] {B};
  \draw [<->] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace*{1cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  pool/.style={
    circle, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, thick,
    inner sep=0pt, minimum size=10mm
  }
]
  \node[pool] (A)              {A};
  \node[pool] (B) [right=of A] {B};
  \draw [<->] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace*{1cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  pool/.style={
    circle, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, thick,
    inner sep=0pt, minimum size=10mm
  }
]
  \node[pool] (A)              {A};
  \node[pool] (B) [right=of A] {B};
  \draw [<->] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace*{1cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  pool/.style={
    circle, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, thick,
    inner sep=0pt, minimum size=10mm
  }
]
  \node[pool] (A)              {A};
  \node[pool] (B) [right=of A] {B};
  \draw [<->] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t][][s]{.1\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[dash pattern=on 3pt off 6pt] (0,0.0) -- (0,10);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t][][s]{.45\linewidth}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  pool/.style={
    circle, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, thick,
    inner sep=0pt, minimum size=10mm
  }
]
  \node[pool] (A)              {A};
  \node[pool] (B) [right=of A] {B};
  \draw [<->] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace*{1cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  pool/.style={
    circle, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, thick,
    inner sep=0pt, minimum size=10mm
  }
]
  \node[pool] (A)              {A};
  \node[pool] (B) [right=of A] {B};
  \draw [<->] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace*{1cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  pool/.style={
    circle, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, thick,
    inner sep=0pt, minimum size=10mm
  }
]
  \node[pool] (A)              {A};
  \node[pool] (B) [right=of A] {B};
  \draw [<->] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace*{1cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  pool/.style={
    circle, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, thick,
    inner sep=0pt, minimum size=10mm
  }
]
  \node[pool] (A)              {A};
  \node[pool] (B) [right=of A] {B};
  \draw [<->] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

\caption{Numerous images.}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Following is the output:

[image]

The second minipage does not obey top alignment. I want to insert the dotted line at the center of the space between two columns of TikZ images. How to fix this or is there a better way of achieving the desired output?

Comment: Vertically centered minipages (`\begin{minipage}[c]`) should work here. I'd also shorten the dashed vertical line, probably to `(0,0.0) -- (0,8)` and add `\centering` to all three minipage environments.

Comment: If you pictures are these or something similar, you probably should consider to draw all in the same `\tikzpicture`.

Comment: The [t] and [b] options for minipages refer to the first and last baselines, not the actual top and bottoms.  [c] use the actual top and bottom, but offsets the baseline by `\dimexpr 0.5\dp\strutbox-0.5\ht\strutbox`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shows how to use the [baseline] option of tikz to align the actual tops of the images.

Note that if the second optional argument is missing, the third is irrelevant.  They are, after all, optional.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north),
  pool/.style={
    circle, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, thick,
    inner sep=0pt, minimum size=10mm
  }
]
  \node[pool] (A)              {A};
  \node[pool] (B) [right=of A] {B};
  \draw [<->] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  pool/.style={
    circle, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, thick,
    inner sep=0pt, minimum size=10mm
  }
]
  \node[pool] (A)              {A};
  \node[pool] (B) [right=of A] {B};
  \draw [<->] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  pool/.style={
    circle, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, thick,
    inner sep=0pt, minimum size=10mm
  }
]
  \node[pool] (A)              {A};
  \node[pool] (B) [right=of A] {B};
  \draw [<->] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace*{1cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  pool/.style={
    circle, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, thick,
    inner sep=0pt, minimum size=10mm
  }
]
  \node[pool] (A)              {A};
  \node[pool] (B) [right=of A] {B};
  \draw [<->] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}% what you put here matters
\begin{minipage}[t]{.1\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]
 \draw[dash pattern=on 3pt off 6pt] (0,0.0) -- (0,10);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}% what you put here matters
\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\linewidth}

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north),
  pool/.style={
    circle, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, thick,
    inner sep=0pt, minimum size=10mm
  }
]
  \node[pool] (A)              {A};
  \node[pool] (B) [right=of A] {B};
  \draw [<->] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  pool/.style={
    circle, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, thick,
    inner sep=0pt, minimum size=10mm
  }
]
  \node[pool] (A)              {A};
  \node[pool] (B) [right=of A] {B};
  \draw [<->] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  pool/.style={
    circle, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, thick,
    inner sep=0pt, minimum size=10mm
  }
]
  \node[pool] (A)              {A};
  \node[pool] (B) [right=of A] {B};
  \draw [<->] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  pool/.style={
    circle, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, thick,
    inner sep=0pt, minimum size=10mm
  }
]
  \node[pool] (A)              {A};
  \node[pool] (B) [right=of A] {B};
  \draw [<->] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

\caption{Numerous images.}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

With three vertically centered minipages or with a single `tikzpicture` environment:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\begin{minipage}[c]{.45\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  pool/.style={
    circle, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, thick,
    inner sep=0pt, minimum size=10mm
  }
]
  \node[pool] (A)              {A};
  \node[pool] (B) [right=of A] {B};
  \draw [<->] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace*{1cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  pool/.style={
    circle, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, thick,
    inner sep=0pt, minimum size=10mm
  }
]
  \node[pool] (A)              {A};
  \node[pool] (B) [right=of A] {B};
  \draw [<->] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace*{1cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  pool/.style={
    circle, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, thick,
    inner sep=0pt, minimum size=10mm
  }
]
  \node[pool] (A)              {A};
  \node[pool] (B) [right=of A] {B};
  \draw [<->] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace*{1cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  pool/.style={
    circle, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, thick,
    inner sep=0pt, minimum size=10mm
  }
]
  \node[pool] (A)              {A};
  \node[pool] (B) [right=of A] {B};
  \draw [<->] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[c]{.1\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[dash pattern=on 3pt off 6pt] (0,0.0) -- (0,8);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[c]{.45\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  pool/.style={
    circle, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, thick,
    inner sep=0pt, minimum size=10mm
  }
]
  \node[pool] (A)              {A};
  \node[pool] (B) [right=of A] {B};
  \draw [<->] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace*{1cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  pool/.style={
    circle, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, thick,
    inner sep=0pt, minimum size=10mm
  }
]
  \node[pool] (A)              {A};
  \node[pool] (B) [right=of A] {B};
  \draw [<->] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace*{1cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  pool/.style={
    circle, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, thick,
    inner sep=0pt, minimum size=10mm
  }
]
  \node[pool] (A)              {A};
  \node[pool] (B) [right=of A] {B};
  \draw [<->] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace*{1cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  pool/.style={
    circle, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, thick,
    inner sep=0pt, minimum size=10mm
  }
]
  \node[pool] (A)              {A};
  \node[pool] (B) [right=of A] {B};
  \draw [<->] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

\caption{Numerous images.}

\end{figure}


\begin{figure}

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  pool/.style={
    circle, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, thick,
    inner sep=0pt, minimum size=10mm
  }
]
  \node[pool] (A1)               {A};
  \node[pool] (B1) [right=of A1] {B};
  \draw [<->] (A1) -- (B1);

  \node[pool] (A2) [below=of A1] {A};
  \node[pool] (B2) [right=of A2] {B};
  \draw [<->] (A2) -- (B2);
  
  \node[pool] (A3) [below=of A2] {A};
  \node[pool] (B3) [right=of A3] {B};
  \draw [<->] (A3) -- (B3);

  \node[pool] (A4) [below=of A3] {A};
  \node[pool] (B4) [right=of A4] {B};
  \draw [<->] (A4) -- (B4);

  \node[pool] (A5) [right=3cm of B1] {A};
  \node[pool] (B5) [right=of A5] {B};
  \draw [<->] (A5) -- (B5);

  \node[pool] (A6) [below=of A5] {A};
  \node[pool] (B6) [right=of A6] {B};
  \draw [<->] (A6) -- (B6);
  
  \node[pool] (A7) [below=of A6] {A};
  \node[pool] (B7) [right=of A7] {B};
  \draw [<->] (A7) -- (B7);

  \node[pool] (A8) [below=of A7] {A};
  \node[pool] (B8) [right=of A8] {B};
  \draw [<->] (A8) -- (B8); 

  
  \node (C1) at ($(B1.north)!0.5!(A5.north)$) {};
  \node (C2) at ($(B4.south)!0.5!(A8.south)$) {};
  \draw[dash pattern=on 3pt off 6pt] (C1) -- (C2); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{Numerous images.}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```